# New OLEDB driver (MSOLEDBSQL) fails to store fraction part of datetime(.fff) in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, oledb

I am using dot net application with c#. As i want to disable TLS 1.0.I have to change old OLEDB driver to new one (MSOLEDBSQL).

But problem is when i am going to store date value with milliseconds into sql server. New driver stores only `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`. I want `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.fff`

I am trying with below code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, m_conn, m_trans);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-03-23 11:22:33.123");
OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("", OleDbType.Date);
param.Value = dt;
param.Size = 16;
param.Precision = 23;
param.Scale = 3;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(table);
da.Dispose();
cmd.Dispose();
```

is new driver omits fraction part of datetime? What are the changes required if i want to store date with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

We're having a similar issue where we with the new MSOLEDBSQL driver have `'DataTypeCompatibility=80'` in the connection string. This change in combination with not specifying the scale explicitly results in seconds as well as factional seconds being truncated.

As such, a value represented as

```
'1994-08-21 21:21:36.123'
```

will be saved as

```
'1994-08-21 21:21:00.000'
```

In your case however, have you tried changing the parameter's OLE DB type to DBTimeStamp?

Client to Server conversion from the *Date* type to *DbTimeStamp* (datetime/datetime2) seems to use the following logic (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/ole-db-date-time/conversions-performed-from-client-to-server?view=sql-server-2017):

> Conversion semantics prior to SQL Server 2008 for DBTYPE_DATE are maintained. Fractional seconds are truncated to zero.